# Access Canadian institutions with Plaid

Tags: plaid

I have recently integrated with Plaid (production account) to get the list of transactions. The US institutions work well.

The problem is that when I try to get Canada ("CA") it returns HTTP 400:

```
{
  "display_message": null,
  "documentation_url": "https://plaid.com/docs/#create-link-token",
  "error_code": "INVALID_PRODUCT",
  "error_message": "client is not authorized to access the following products: [\"transactions\"]",
  "error_type": "INVALID_INPUT",
  "request_id": "NsltK34WXQD84IP"
}
```

This is the Python request:

```
LinkTokenCreateRequest(
            products=[Products("transactions")],
            client_name="Company",
            country_codes=[CountryCode("CA")],
            language="en",
            user=LinkTokenCreateRequestUser(client_user_id=client_user_id),
        )
```

Any idea why this error happens when using "CA" but not "US"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your developer account might only be enabled for the US, in which case you'll have to ask Plaid that it also be enabled for Canadian institutions  -- Plaid used to be auto-enabled for both US and Canada for new accounts but it's possible that that has changed. To request access, you can submit a support ticket or contact sales.